# Validate JSON-LD and Schema.org

Tags: validation, schema.org, json-ld

I am looking for a good validator to test my Schema.org used in JSON-LD. I searched around but really can't find a good validator to test this.

Anyone knows where I can find a good validator?

The [Google validator](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) doesn't validate my JSON-LD.

Example of implementation:

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "John Doe",
  "jobTitle": "Graduate research assistant",
  "affiliation": "University of Dreams",
  "additionalName": "Johnny",
  "url": "http://www.example.com",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "1234 Peach Drive",
    "addressLocality": "Wonderland",
    "addressRegion": "Georgia"
  }
```

Comment: Note that asking for a tool is off-topic here. Such questions can be asked on [softwarerecs.se]. But you would have to provide more details, like: What exactly do you want to validate, and why doesn’t (for example) Google’s tool work for you?

Comment: @unot "Software Recommendations" is a dead-end/graveyard

Comment: I validated your code snipped with google test tool you listed.. and you're missing closing "}"

Comment: @Thomas Crawford Did you found any solution ? Please share.

Comment: @infiniteLearner Sorry i can't remember anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't run into any errors or warnings in the Structured Data Testing tool then your structured data is validated. Just testing the little snippet you posted, all seems to be ok (but you're missing an ending "}").

If what you're seeking is what markup you *should* or *shouldn't* use based on  a webpage, one would need more topical information to answer that (and you're not actually looking for a "validator" at that point).